# Worker Role Keeps Recycling After October 2012 Update

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I updated a working solution to use the October 2012 release. Since then my worker roles keep recycling. I am unable to hit any breakpoints either in OnStart on OnStop or Run.

the web role is working as expected.

I activated all the exceptions for the debug and nothing seems to be caught. its as if the roles running in the instances are default roles and not my code.

anyone have any insight

Comment: so far, I have found that the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime version moved to 1.8

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the Event Log?

Comment: no errors, no exceptions, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I upgraded my solution to use the latest Windows Azure SDK. I moved from 1.7 to 1.8.

But the references to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime' were still pointing to 1.7. the SDKs are installed side by site and do not one over the other.

Since the versions did not match my code never got executed by the roles in the emulator and on windows azure. The code the was executed was the default Role implementation and the method Run kept on completing, in turn causing the role to keep recycling.